# Data is returning with wrong response type in Loopback

Tags: angularjs, loopbackjs, strongloop

Album->Tracklist<-Songs

I have 3 Models. I have this sort of relationship. Means Album is related with Song and Song again is related with has Many relationship using through Model Tracklist.

I wish to fetch records thats also I am succeeded, but it giving me error on console of $resource.badcfg. When I google its because I am expecting parameter as object and it is returning array. How to resolve this. I wish to find all records having this url. 'http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/Albums/60/songs'

```
Album.songs.
        .findById({id: $stateParams.itemId})
        .$promise
        .then(function (data) {
            $scope.detail = data;
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need pass success and error callbacks as params:

```
Album.songs.
  .findById({id: $stateParams.itemId},
    function(data) {
      $scope.detail = data;
    }, function(error) {
      console.log(error)
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

To query all songs that belongs to 60 Album, try

`Album.songs({ id: $stateParams.itemId })`

You can also browse angular resource api using build-in tool - Docular, just execute `sudo lb-ng-doc path/to/angular-sdk.js`

Comment: Can you please help to generate this file. When I execute this command to empty folder its saying angular-sdk.js not found. Please help.

Comment: @Sankalp, check here http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/AngularJS+JavaScript+SDK